# ngAfterContentChecked() not understandable + angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-services

I have been trying to figure out the meaning of `ngAfterContentChecked()` and  `ngAfterViewChecked()` for some time. Have tried various posts, but still can't understand their exact meaning. Following is the definition given in angular.io.
Can somebody explain it properly with some goood example.

```
ngAfterViewChecked()- Respond after Angular checks the component's views and child views.
Called after the ngAfterViewInit and every subsequent ngAfterContentChecked().
A component-only hook.

ngAfterContentChecked()- Respond after Angular checks the content projected into the component.
Called after the ngAfterContentInit() and every subsequent ngDoCheck().
A component-only hook.
```

Comment: try reading this: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#aftercontent and https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#afterview

Answer (score 2):

Let's say we have this Html

```
<div> // div A
  <app-my-component>
    <div>
      this is some content for the component app-my-component
    </div>
  </app-my-component>
</div> // div B
```

Let's say we have this component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  template: `
    <div> // div C
      here is the View HTML but below we receive content html
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div> // div D
  `
})
```

In our component from div A all the way through div B that is the View. So AfterViewChecked will run when we reach B. The content is everything that resides in the ng-content tag. So AfterContentChecked will run when we reach div D.  However any and I mean any changes to the view can trigger an additional AfterViewCheck which should also trigger an AfterContentCheck